# Will I lose a solution if I solve the trig equation the way it's done in this video?

Tags: trigonometry

[Video link to youtube and is timestamped so if you click here you'll see when he divides by cos I can't write using latex and it'll just take a second to see the what transpires.](https://youtube.com/watch?v=2gy6hhnh2xQ&t=4m55s)

Equation: $2 \sin(θ+60)°=\cos(θ-45)°$

[image]

In the video this guy divides both sides by cos theta and my concern is that if theta were zero then would a solution be lost? He's a math teacher so I'm not sure if he made a mistake or not.

Comment: I'd rather not watch a $7$-minute video to learn what your questions is.  Please type the equation that concerns you.

Comment: And where does he divide by $\cos\theta$?  Please edit your question so that it is complete and self-contained.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dividing by *anything* is always perfectly valid -- but don't forget that you must **always** also include the caveat from that point forward that the divisor is not equal to zero. Most people just drop that condition altogether, which is patently **incorrect**. In your case, you must also include the caveat that $\cos\theta\neq 0$.

This means you must consider the case $\cos\theta=0$ separately.

You never "lose a solution" by doing this if you carry the caveat forward. That is exactly the reason to do so.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos\theta\neq 0$, if otherwise $\sqrt{2}\sin\theta=\sin\theta$ (4th row)

$\sin\theta=0$, which is impossible, since $\cos\theta= 0$ simultaneously.